Else condition in sld styling
I have a point table which I style using the PropertyName Type. I have defined the rules and style for many types but I want to catch any unknown type which I have missed.
Isnt there some easier way than using multiple PropertyIsNotEqualTo to exclude all the types I have already styled?
    <Rule>
      <Name>Unknown type</Name>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:And>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>54</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>58</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>59</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>61</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>62</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>63</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>64</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>65</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>66</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>78</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>86</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo> <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>112</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
      </ogc:And>
    </ogc:Filter>


You need a rule with an elsefilter filter, which oddly is in the SLD namespace not the ogc one.
